# Как активировать SetActive(false) GameObject в Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть активный объект с прикреленным скриптом. Есть два объекта в режиме SetActive(false).

```
if (db_char_id != char_id)
            {
                CreatePlayer = gameObject.AddComponent<CreatePlayerScript>();
                CreatePlayer.RecUserId(char_id);

                CreatePlayer.SetActiveOn();

                Debug.Log("Open CreatePlayerPanel");
            }
            if (db_char_id == char_id)
            {
                Game = gameObject.AddComponent<GameScript>();

                Game.SetActiveOn();

                Debug.Log("Open GamePanel");
            }
```

Срабатывает логика и запускает метод SetActiveOn() в скрипте, прикрепленном к неактивному объекту на сцене.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameScript : MonoBehaviour {

public void SetActiveOn()
{
    gameObject.SetActive(true);
}

}
```

Отладчик спокойно проходит все этапы. В Unity гаснет главное окно (как и положено, командой gameObject.SetActive(false);), но не срабатывает активация неактивного объекта. Почему? Ошибок не выдает.

Comment: `Game = gameObject.AddComponent<GameScript>();` - быть может вы имели в виду `GetComponent`, а не `AddComponent` ? ...... вот этот код с ифами где вызывается? в каком-нибудь методе `Update` неактивного объекта?

Comment: if используется в скрипте пустого активного объекта на сцене. Вызывается методом при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: ну вот тогда непонятна логика..... когда вы в нем пишите `gameObject.AddComponent<GameScript>();` или `gameObject.AddComponent<CreatePlayerScript>();`  - вы именно *этому активному* объекту добавляете скрипт.... в итоге вы `SetActiveOn` вызываете совсем не на неактивном объекте вовсе.............. `Game` и `CreatePlayer` - это какие-то публичные поля, в которых  через инспектор расположены объекты?

Comment: Возможно вы правы. Я был крепко уверен, что запущенный метод с активацией, лежащий на неактивном объекте, активирует данный объект. Game и CreatePlayer это public CreatePlayerScript CreateScript и public GameScript Game, подключение к скриптам, лежашим на неактивных объектах

Comment: У меня подозрения вот к чему. Активный объект гасит команда gameObject.SetActive(false); в методе Start. Но как сделать обратное при неактивном объекте? Есть видео: [ссылка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VpAUyeBQpw)

Comment: Собственно, при нажатии на кнопку - посмотрите в инспекторе на тот самый объект, на котором находится скрипт с ифами. Вы увидите, что вы именно ему добавляете компонент. Потому что `AddComponent` - добавляет его.... Вам нужно не добавлять его, а брать, как я писал выше. Причем не у данного объекта с текущим скриптом, а у тех самых неактивных объектов. Например будет так: `GameScript gameComponent = Game.GetComponent<GameScript>();

                gameComponent.SetActiveOn();`...... т.е. ключевое тут `Game.GetComponent<GameScript>()`  - берете компонент у объекта, который лежит в поле `Game`

Comment: А отрабатывает `SetActiveOn` - вполне по вышеописанной причине Т.к. вы добавляете компонент (AddComponent) на текущий объект с данным скриптом, у него, как раз, он (этот добавленный компонент) и срабатывает.

Comment: Значит мой LoginScript берет в себя AfterLoginScritp, который берет в себя CreatePlayerScript и GameScript, оставаясь все это время LoginScript, так как все обращения через AddComponent. Ну это многое объясняет)))